# Can I transfer purchased apps+license info between devices via adb?

Tags: data-transfer

I've some desk phones that are basically a 7-ish-inch tablet with a handset hanging next to it. Since nobody uses the phone anymore, the only thing they've served for these days was as control surfaces for the place. For that I use a kiosked browser or the an app that connects to my automation controller.

The problem is is that these things have grown ancient and no longer have their certificate stores current enough to connect to anything encrypted. Among those things; the Play Store and even the local servers but the app is compatible, I know that because it was already installed in one of them that was factory restored by mistake.

Trying to revive an Android TV box recently, I learned how to push apps through `adb` wirelessly, I already connected to the reset phone and it doesn't seems like a big deal sideloading the app, the problem is the license information. Using this awesome file manager app, *FX*, that shows a lot of metadata about just about anything, I saw that the app requested under "UNGROUPED PERMISSIONS" (no idea) two that caught my attention: ***Google Play billing service*** and ***Play Install Referrer API***. This sort of worries me because I bought this netdiag utility app a while back, that **for it to remain licensed, I had to be signed up to Google's services** which was beyond infuriating, I have a feeling there might be some of that in this app too. *On the other hand,* the other devices that weren't reset still have the app working and they were logged off, their certificates are old as well, and on top of that the phones are on a network without Internet access. This gives me a little hope. :)

Any suggestion?

Comment: How non-free apps from PlayStore check their license is up to the app developer. So don't check at all (if you have the APK you have the licensed version). Others use the Google recommended way to ask GooglePlayServices through API. Not sure how Google handles the situation if PlayServices can't phone home anymore, thus how long license information are cached.

Comment: I haven't seen them lately but remember when there were a ton of apps that, to license them, you purchased a companion app? I didn't like these because while some would hide themselves, some wouldn't which created more clutter in an already cluttered OS. *NOW*, I'm seeing their merits... :(